# Firebase Remote Config (Web) always uses default values for Samsung Internet

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-remote-config

I've tried to use the Javascript SDK for Firebase Remote Config with my website. For some reason the code works fine when customers browse the website with Chrome, Edge, Vivaldi, and some other browsers. But when the site is viewed using Samsung Internet, or Polypane, the remote config always uses the default values supplied in code, without reaching for the existing ones from the firebase online project. Is someone able to direct me how I might fix this?
Code is below:

```
<script>
    
      const remoteConfig = firebase.remoteConfig();
          remoteConfig.settings = {
            
              fetchTimeMillis: 60000,
              minimumFetchIntervalMillis: 300000

          }
          
          remoteConfig.defaultConfig = ({
  'maintenance_mode_enabled': "false",
              'maintenance_mode_message': "Apologies, our website is unavailable at present. Please direct your enquiries to us by email, or check back here later."
});
        
          
          
          
          
         remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
  .then(() => {
              console.log("Thinking");
              
        const val = remoteConfig.getValue("maintenance_mode_enabled");
        const val2 = remoteConfig.getValue("maintenance_mode_message");
                      console.log(val);
                      console.log(val2);
        const maintenance_element = document.getElementById('maintenancemodeoverlay');
              const maintenance_message = document.getElementById('maintenancemodemessage');
              if(val._value=="true" && sessionStorage.bypass != "true"){
                          console.log("Enabling");
                  
                  maintenance_element.style.visibility = "visible";
                  maintenance_message.innerHTML = val2._value;
                  console.log(val2._value);
              }
        
              
              
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Firebase Remote Config failed to initialize', err);
  });
  
         
      </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was actually a bug in Firebase's system. After contacting support, they forwarded the bug onto their software engineers who fixed the issue within a day.

Answer (score 1):

this could mostly be the issue of setting of those 2 browsers, as your code is working fine in other browsers, I don't see any issue in your code. you can check the local setting of your browser and see if there you find some solution there.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I didn't make any errors above. I've now got in touch with Firebase Support who in turn are speaking with their software engineers, as they were able to reproduce the issue. Thanks once again for your time!

Comment: in that case, please put the solution here, that would be really appreciated